# How to uninstall a Fire fox add-on that doesn't want to be uninstalled?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, uninstall

Let's say I installed a program, called "E" . Said  program requests to install a Firefox add-on. Now the add-on doesn't work due to being incompatible. Because it came with E i uninstall E planning to re-install it with out the add-on, but after the E uninstall finishes the add-on is still there in Firefox, disabled and with the buttons grayed out. Moreover, Firefox displays the "Restart Firefox to uninstall this add-on" message but no matter how many times it's restarted the loop wont end. Is there any way to uninstall E's add-on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this article ["Uninstalling add-ons"](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_FAQs_:_Uninstall_Extensions) from the Mozilla FAQ.
I believe it covers all the possibilities.

Comment: +1 The link covers everything relates to addons in Firefox, Thunderbird & Sea Monkey.

Comment: Thnx it's a useful link. I'll try all the option until i can reclaim my Firefox